# How to dynamically turn on or off one appender of rootLogger in log4j2?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

How to dynamically turn on or off one appender of rootLogger in log4j2 by java at runtime?

for example, I wanna disable Console Appender:

```
...
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
...
```

Is it possible?

Comment: IMO you will need to add the appenders programmatically, if you want to manipulate them through code. Here are some similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699358/log4j-creating-modifying-appenders-at-runtime-log-file-recreated-and-not-appe and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909871/how-can-i-access-the-configured-log4j-appenders-at-runtime

Comment: I don't have a lots of context. But maybe you can disable/enable it via JMX  at runtime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can programmatically add or remove an appender. In your case let's remove `Console`

```
final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
config.getRootLogger().removeAppender("CONSOLE");
ctx.updateLoggers();
```

There is a [LifeCycle](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LifeCycle.html) interface with methods `stop` and `start`, but it looks like you can not restart an appender after it was stopped.

Comment: Why not to call stop() method after .removeAppender() method? Why one cannot restart an appender?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a script filter to the console appenderref that checks the value of a system property. Then just set the property when you want logging to the console disabled. Reset it when you want it turned back on.