# java log4j add one more logger from your code

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Im using Log4j and i have the following problem: is there a way to add one more logger from your code ? (not root logger). 
In my config file, i set up the following two loggers :

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, ALogFile
log4j.logger.BLog=INFO,BLog
```

I would like to remove second line from config file and add BLog from code. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent code should be:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("BLog");
logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);    
logger.addAppender(Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("BLog")); // see notes below
```

I.e. you obtain a `Logger` object for the name `BLog`, you then set the level to `INFO` and attach the appender you've presumable defined elsewhere in your config file, called `BLog`.

Note: based on the answers from [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909871/how-can-i-access-the-configured-log4j-appenders-at-runtime), you may need to attach the appender to a logger in order to be able to reference it, as my code does above. Or just define the appender in your code.